# Use ant with Netbeans Save Actions

Tags: java, php, netbeans, ant, ide

Does a plugin exist that lets me run custom *ant tasks* on file save?
Netbeans currently only seems to have support for some predefined functions.

If such a plugin does not exist, how would I create one? Could someone line up the exact steps, I am quite good at Java myself, however I have never created a Netbeans plugin.

And to people asking if I really want it on save: Yes. Because I want to define a version (like 1.0.129) that gets automatically incremented every time a file in my PHP Project gets saved.

Comment: Have you find a solution?

Comment: @Lucio No, I haven't unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create your own plugin. Use http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/javadoc/org-netbeans-modules-editor-lib2/org/netbeans/spi/editor/document/OnSaveTask.Factory.html

Comment: Any clue what to do with that interface? Any link to a guide or HOWTO write a plugin, at least to know where to start, would be cool.